Harmonic Analysis on Gel'fand Pairs
I would be very grateful if someone could provide me with the following course material:
J. FARAUT. Harmonic Analysis on Gel'fand Pairs and Hyperbolic Spaces, CIMPA Courses, Nancy 1, France. (1982)
Thank you very much.
